# Dynamically render select choices Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates, htmx

I posted a screenshot below to hopefully make this easier to understand so I will reference it in my question.

I am trying to create a recipe cost calculator app. I have 3 model namely `Recipe`, `RecipeIngredient` and `Ingredient`

The user will add ingredients to the database and then create recipes using those ingredients throught the `RecipeIngredient` model.

When creating an `Ingredient` the user selects a unit eg. (grams). Now when the user goes to create a `Recipe` (see screenshot below) I want to only display the units that are relevant to that ingredient and not all of them for eg. A user added Beef and the unit was grams now when the user is adding a `RecipeIngredient` to the `Recipe` I want them  to only be able to select from the "Weight" category in the example (see screenshot below). The reason for this is because grams can't be converted to milliliters and so it shouldn't even be a choice.

If anything is unclear or you need more information just let me know.

## Models

#### Recipe Models

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

from ingredients.models import Ingredient

class Recipe(models.Model):
    """Store recipe information and costs"""

    class Meta:
        """Meta definition for Recipe."""

        verbose_name = "Recipe"
        verbose_name_plural = "Recipes"
        ordering = ("name",)

    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=155)
    yield_count = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    yield_units = models.CharField(max_length=155, default="servings")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("recipe:detail", kwargs={"id": self.pk})

    def get_update_url(self):
        return reverse("recipe:update", kwargs={"id": self.pk})


class RecipeIngredient(models.Model):
    """Holds more information about how much of a certain ingredient is used inside a recipe"""

    class Meta:
        """Meta definition for RecipeIngredient"""

        verbose_name = "RecipeIngredient"
        verbose_name_plural = "RecipeIngredients"

    # NOTE: User should first choose the ingredient
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe, related_name="ingredients", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient, related_name="ingredient", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    # NOTE: Then the amount an unit should be asked based on that
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=Ingredient.UNIT_CHOICES, default=None)

    def __str__(self):
        """Unicode representation of RecipeIngredient"""
        return self.ingredient.__str__()
```

#### Ingredient Model

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

from pint import UnitRegistry

from .choices import ALL_UNIT_CHOICES


class Ingredient(models.Model):
    """Stores data about an ingredient to be used by a Recipe model."""

    class Meta:
        """Meta definition for Ingredient."""

        verbose_name = "Ingredient"
        verbose_name_plural = "Ingredients"
        ordering = ("name",)

    # Unit choices that will display in a dropdown
    # It will be ordered by group (eg. Weight, Volume)
    UNIT_CHOICES = ALL_UNIT_CHOICES

    ureg = UnitRegistry()

    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    size = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=UNIT_CHOICES, default=None)

    def __str__(self):
        """Unicode representation of Ingredient."""
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """Return absolute url for Ingredient"""
        return reverse("ingredient:detail", kwargs={"id": self.pk})

    def get_update_url(self):
        """Return the url for update page"""
        return reverse("ingredient:update", kwargs={"id": self.pk})

    def get_delete_url(self):
        return reverse("ingredient:delete", kwargs={"id": self.pk})

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.unit = self.ureg.Unit(self.unit)

        super(Ingredient, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

## Views

```
def create_recipe(request):
    template_name = "recipes/create.html"

    form = CreateRecipeForm(request.POST or None)
    ingredient_choice_form = IngredientChoiceForm(request.POST or None, request=request)
    Formset = modelformset_factory(RecipeIngredient, form=CreateRecipeIngredientForm, extra=0)
    formset = Formset(request.POST or None, queryset=Recipe.objects.none())

    context = {
        "form": form,
        "ingredient_choice_form": ingredient_choice_form,
        "formset": formset,
    }

    print(request.POST)

    return render(request, template_name, context)

# This is the view being calle by HTMX everytime an ingredient is selected
def get_recipe_ingredient_details(request):
    template_name = "recipes/hx_snippets/add_recipe_ingredient_details.html"

    ingredient_id = request.GET.get("ingredients")

    if not ingredient_id:
        return HttpResponse("")

    ingredient = Ingredient.objects.get(id=ingredient_id)
    choices = get_unit_group(ingredient.unit)

    Formset = modelformset_factory(RecipeIngredient, form=CreateRecipeIngredientForm, extra=1)
    formset = Formset(
        request.POST or None,
        queryset=RecipeIngredient.objects.none(),
        initial=[
            {
                "ingredient": ingredient,
                "unit": choices,
            },
        ],
    )

    context = {
        "formset": formset,
        "ingredient": ingredient,
    }
```

## Templates

#### Template returned by HTMX request

```
<p>
    {% for form in formset %}
        {{ form }}
    {% endfor %}
</p>
```

#### main create template

```
{% block content %}
    <h1>Create Recipe</h1>

    <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}

        {{ form.as_p }}

        <h3>Add ingredients</h3>
        {{ formset.management_form }}
        <div id="ingredient-form"></div>
        {{ ingredient_choice_form.as_p }} <-- this is an HTMX get request that calls the get_recipe_ingredient_details view
        
        <p><button type="submit">Create</button></p>
    </form>
{% endblock content %}


{% block scripts %}
    <script src="{% static 'js/recipes/addFormsetField.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock scripts %}
```

## Choices.py

```
from django.db import models


class WeightUnitChoices(models.TextChoices):
    GRAMS = "gram", "gram"
    OZ = "ounce", "ounce"
    LBS = "pound", "pound"
    KG = "kilogram", "kilogram"
    T = "tonne", "tonne"


class VolumeUnitChoices(models.TextChoices):
    ML = "milliliter", "milliliter"
    L = "liter", "liter"
    TSP = "teaspoon", "teaspoon"
    TBPS = "tablespoon", "tablespoon"


ALL_UNIT_CHOICES = [
    (None, "Select Unit"),
    ("Weight", WeightUnitChoices.choices),
    ("Volume", VolumeUnitChoices.choices),
]


def get_unit_group(unit):
    """returns the unit group to which unit belongs to"""
    match unit:
        case unit if unit in dict(WeightUnitChoices.choices):
            return WeightUnitChoices.choices
        case unit if unit in dict(VolumeUnitChoices.choices):
            return VolumeUnitChoices.choices
        case _:
            # Return all available units
            return ALL_UNIT_CHOICES
```

## Screenshot

[image]

Comment: You need to store the unit category for an ingredient beforehand and display only the corresponding category on the form. How does `ALL_UNIT_CHOICES` look like?

Comment: Hi Dauros, I added the choices.py to my post for more clarity. It basically creates different choice groups for different units. ```ALL_UNIT_CHOICES``` returns all the available choices to be used inside the forms. On the other side ```get_unit_group``` will return the group a specific ```unit``` belongs to eg. its passed "grams" it will return the ```WeightUnitChoices```

Comment: Thanks. In the 'main create template' where is the HTMX request? Your comment there is a unclear for me, because that line prints a form, it is not making a HTMX GET request. Furthermore the `get_recipe_ingredient_details` missing the `return render(...)` line at the end, but maybe you just missed that line during copy-pasting the code here.

Comment: I would love to get a response on @Dauros question!